# NullPointerException even when variables are not null

Tags: java, object, nullpointerexception, queue

I'm currently designing a program to simulate an airport. I ran into a problem and I've already tried my best to figure out the problem and posting to this site was my final resort.

It keeps giving me a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at AirportApp.main(AirportApp.java:119)" which is under the //Landings section with the code

```
System.out.println(plane1.getCapacity());
```

The reason I did the print is to make sure plane1.getCapacity isn't a null. This is because when I tried the code below it

```
if(plane1.getCapacity() < 300);
```

it gave me the NullPointerException error. I did the print and it didn't return a null.

What I'm trying to do here is whenever a plane lands, it will be assigned to an empty gate. If the plane has a capacity of 300 or more, it will be assigned to the 4th or 5th gate only. The other planes can be assigned to any gate.

What I noticed was that the error happens only when the capacity is over 300.

I've already looked at my code over and over again making sure all variables were initialized and I still could not find anything wrong. Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated. Apologies for the messy code.

Main class.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AirportApp {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rn = new Random();

    String [] flightNames = {"SQ", "MI", "TZ", "TR", "EK", "MO", "FC"};
    int [] flightNum = {8421, 5361, 6342, 6135, 8424, 7424, 5435};

    Queue landingRunway = new Queue(10);
    Queue takeoffRunway = new Queue(10);
    Queue planesQueue = new Queue(100);
    Queue gatesQueue = new Queue(100);
    ArrayList<Gate> allGates = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 1 ; i < 6 ; i++)
    {
        allGates.add(new Gate(i, 0, 0, true));
    }

    int minutes = 0;
    int planesMissedTime = 0;
    Boolean highWinds = null;
    int tookOffPlanes = 0;
    int smallCapPlanes = 0;
    int largeCapPlanes = 0;
    int landedPlanes = 0;

    System.out.println("Please key in the number of minutes you want " 
                        + "the program to run: ");
    int desiredMinutes = sc.nextInt();

    while(minutes < desiredMinutes)
    {
        //Randomise wind warnings
        int windRandom = rn.nextInt(2) + 1;
        if(windRandom == 1)
        {
            highWinds = true;
        }
        if(windRandom == 2)
        {
            highWinds = false;
        }

        //Empty the gates

        for(Gate c : allGates)
        {
            if(c.getAvailability() == false)
            {
                c.addMinInQueue(1);
                if(c.getMinInQueue() == 15)
                {
                    c.isAvailable();
                }
            }
        }

        //Every 2 minutes

        if(minutes % 2 == 0)
        {
            //Randomise flight names and number

            int index = rn.nextInt(flightNames.length);
            int index1 = rn.nextInt(flightNum.length);
            String name = flightNames[index];
            int num = flightNum[index1];

            //Randomise plane assignment

            int planeDirection = rn.nextInt(2) + 1;
            int planeCap = rn.nextInt(401) + 100;

            //Arrival Planes

            if(planeDirection == 1)
            {
                planesQueue.enqueue(new Plane(num, name, planeCap, 5 , 0 ));
                System.out.println("A plane has been generated.");
            }

            //Departure Planes

            if(planeDirection == 2)
            {
                planesQueue.enqueue(new Plane(num, name, planeCap, 0 , 5 ));
                System.out.println("A plane has been generated.");
            }

            //Take-Offs

            if(!takeoffRunway.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("A plane has departed.");
                Plane departPlane = (Plane) takeoffRunway.dequeue();
                if (departPlane.getCapacity() < 300)
                {
                    smallCapPlanes++;
                }
                tookOffPlanes++;
            }
        }

        //Landings

        if(minutes % 3 == 0 && !landingRunway.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("A plane has landed.");
            gatesQueue.enqueue(landingRunway.dequeue());
            landedPlanes++;
            loop1:
            for(Gate e : allGates)
            {
                if(e.getAvailability() == true)
                {
                    Plane plane1 = (Plane) gatesQueue.dequeue();
                    System.out.println(plane1.getCapacity());
                    if(plane1.getCapacity() < 300)
                    {
                        e.addNumOfPlanes(1);
                        e.setAvailability(false);
                        break loop1;
                    }
                    if(plane1.getCapacity() > 300)
                    {
                         largeCapPlanes++;
                        if(e.getGateId() == 4 || e.getGateId() == 5)
                        {
                            e.addNumOfPlanes(1);
                            e.setAvailability(false);
                            break loop1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Plane assigned to takeoff or landing queue

        if(minutes % 5 == 0)
        {
            Plane item = (Plane) planesQueue.peek();
            if(item.getArrivalTime() == 5 && landingRunway.isEmpty()
                    && highWinds == false)
            {
                landingRunway.enqueue(planesQueue.dequeue());
                System.out.println("A plane has been assigned to " 
                                    + "the landing queue.");
            }
            else if(item.getDepartureTime() == 5 &&
                    takeoffRunway.isEmpty() && highWinds == false)
            {
                takeoffRunway.enqueue(planesQueue.dequeue());
                System.out.println("A plane has been assigned to " 
                                    + "the takeoff queue.");
            }
            else
            {
                planesMissedTime++;
            }
        }
        minutes++;
    }
```

Class 1

```
public class Plane 
{
private int flightNo;
private String flightName;
private int capacity;
private int timeOfArrival;
private int timeOfDeparture;
private int delayTime;

public Plane(int flightNo, String flightName, int capacity, 
                int timeOfArrival, int timeOfDeparture)
{
    this.flightNo = flightNo;
    this.flightName = flightName;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.timeOfArrival = timeOfArrival;
    this.timeOfDeparture = timeOfDeparture;
}


public void setFlightNum(int flightNo)
{
    this.flightNo = flightNo;
}

public int getFlightNum()
{
    return this.flightNo;
}

public void setFlightName(String flightName)
{
    this.flightName = flightName;
}

public String getflightName()
{
    return this.flightName;
}

public void addCapacity(int capacity)
{
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public int getCapacity()
{
    return this.capacity;
}

public void setArrivalTime(int newArrivalTime)
{
    this.timeOfArrival = newArrivalTime;
}

public int getArrivalTime()
{
    return this.timeOfArrival;
}

public void setDepartureTime(int newDepartureTime)
{
    this.timeOfDeparture = newDepartureTime;
}

public int getDepartureTime()
{
    return this.timeOfDeparture;
}
}
```

Class 2

```
public class Gate 
{
private int gateID;
private int numOfPlanes;
private int minInQueue;
private boolean availability;

public Gate(int id, int numPlanes, int minQueue, boolean available)
{
    this.gateID = id;
    this.numOfPlanes = numPlanes;
    this.minInQueue = minQueue;
    this.availability = available;
}

public int getGateId()
{
    return this.gateID;
}

public void setGateId(int newID)
{
    this.gateID = newID;
}

public int getNumOfPlanes()
{
    return this.numOfPlanes;
}

public void addNumOfPlanes(int addNum)
{
    this.numOfPlanes += addNum;
}

public int getMinInQueue()
{
    return this.minInQueue;
}

public void setMinInQueue(int setMin)
{
    this.minInQueue = 0;
}

public void addMinInQueue(int addMin)
{
    this.minInQueue += addMin;
}

public boolean getAvailability()
{
    return this.availability;
}

public void setAvailability(Boolean setAvailability)
{
    this.availability = setAvailability; 
}

public void isAvailable()
{
    this.availability = true;
    this.minInQueue = 0;
}
}
```

Queue class

```
class Queue
{
    private int count;
    private int front = 0;      
    private int rear = 0;       
    private Object [] items;    

    public Queue(int maxSize)
    {
            count = 0;
            front = -1;
            rear = -1;
            items = new Object [maxSize];
    }

    public boolean enqueue (Object x)
    {
        if (count == items.length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            rear = (rear + 1) % items.length;
            items[rear] = x;
            if (count == 0) 
            {               
                front = 0;
            }
            count++;
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object dequeue()
    {
        if (count == 0) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        else 
        {
            Object result = items[front]; 
            front = (front + 1) % items.length; 
            count--;
            if (count == 0) 
            {               
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            }

            return result;
        }           
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if (count == 0)
            {
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            return false;
            }
    }

    public Object peek()
    {
        if (count == 0) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return items[front];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I ran the code and I didn't get any exceptions. What numbers do I have to enter to get the exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the second if statement

> `if (plane1.getCapacity() > 300) {
>       largeCapPlanes++;
>       if (e.getGateId() == 4 || e.getGateId() == 5) {
>         e.addNumOfPlanes(1);
>         e.setAvailability(false);
>         break loop1;
>       }
>     }`

You only break your loop if the gate is 4, or 5.  So, if it is not gate 4 or 5, then you code will loop back to the next gate, grab another plane from the queue (which is empty and your `plane1` is now `null`) and then try to get the capacity.  And there you get your null pointer.

Note:  Be careful nesting loops and if statements.  This is where bugs enjoy living.

Happy Coding!

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code and didn't get an error until I tried a large number for the time (1000). I'm assuming the error is with the `Plane plane1 = (Plane) gatesQueue.dequeue();` section. I would throw some debug statements in there to see if for large n that the Queue is generated properly. if `dequeue()` returns `null` then `plane1` will also be `null`

EDIT:

So I debugged it and confirmed that the issue is with your `plane` object in that loop. You enqueue your gates: `gatesQueue.enqueue(landingRunway.dequeue());` then you run a loop: `for(Gate e : allGates)` and then you dequeue: `Plane plane1 = (Plane) gatesQueue.dequeue();`

If you dequeue more than what you enqueue you will return `null`. So you'll either have to change how you do your queue or put a check in that for-loop to check the size of your queue.

The reason you are seeing a number when you do your `System.out.println()` is because it is displaying that, returning to the top of the loop, and then trying to get the `plane` object again before you run the print again.